# Error initializing project with vue-charts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (568:17)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-quasar/lib/loader.js.transform-quasar-imports.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     };
| class DatasetController {
>  static defaults = {};
|  static datasetElementType = null;
|  static dataElementType = null;
```

I would like help to resolve the error.

Comment: More code is needed to understand the full scenario. Like, how are you importing the charts? how did you initialize those?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.